# Is it possible to use a function similar to webViewFinishLoad without delegating?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm creating a framework to manipulate PDFs and at once point I load PDFs using the following code:

```
@IBOutlet var webView1: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let pdf = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("template", withExtension: "pdf", subdirectory: nil, localization: nil)  {
        let req = NSURLRequest(URL: pdf)
        webView1.delegate = self
        self.webView1.loadRequest(req)
    }

}
```

And then making use of the UIWebViewDelegate properties of my ViewController class to benefit from webViewFinishLoad to know when loading is finished.

Is there anyway of achieving this same end result without delegating my webView1 to main view?

Comment: There is no such function called viewDidLoadFinish. Do you mean webViewDidLoad  ?

Comment: Yes. Good catch :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are you looking for is to use a block callback, unfortunately
>   UIWebview doesn't support them.

There are still a lot of Cocoa libraries that don't support Closures. You could use for example ClosureKit to do this.

https://github.com/Reflejo/ClosureKit

Using this library you will be able to do this

```
webView.didFinishLoad = { webView in
    println("didFinishLoad \(webView)")
}
```